# Not able to access laravel routes in apache2 server

Tags: apache, laravel, .htaccess, ubuntu-server

I've deployed a new laravel installation to my server, While doing so I configured my apache2 as following:

I added `000-default.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` as following:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

 <Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

I've my laravel installed into `/var/www/html/stellar` folder now I access my installation through:

```
http://52.39.175.55/stellar/public/
```

But while calling the routes it is not working, Like

```
http://52.39.175.55/stellar/public/oauth/token
```

Here is the screenshot:[image]

But suppose I call through this:

```
http://52.39.175.55/stellar/public/index.php/oauth/token
```

I get the access,

[image]

I tried changing my `public/.htaccess` file to something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /stellar

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Still there is no change, Help me out in this.

Comment: Did you have mod_rewrite enabled? Run `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: @Troyer How can I check that? Here's my complete php info http://52.39.175.55/info.php

Comment: Mod_rewrite is not visible in phpinfo(). You can check with: `apache2ctl -M`

Comment: @Troyer I did that but it ain't helping me out. I can see `rewrite_module (shared)` is available while typing `apache2ctl -M`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your VirtualHost on `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` should look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/stellar/public"
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    <Directory /var/www/html/stellar/public>
      AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart apache2 and it should work.

I hardly recommend you to duplicate the `000-default.conf` file, rename it and include the VirtualHost, then enable it with `a2ensite` command, just because it's more easy to manage.